# QWebEnginePage does not know its contents size

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I have a very simple application using `WebEngineView` and I just wanted to resize the widget displaying to the contents of the html file. I'm expecting it to be 30 pixels wide. Instead my program prints `QSize(0,0)` and even worser the widget is not displayed at all.

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    auto view = new QWebEngineView;
    QString html = "<html><body><div width=30px>Text</div></body></html>";
    view->setHtml(html);
    auto contentsSize=view->page()->contentsSize().toSize();
    qDebug() << contentsSize;
    view->setFixedSize(contentsSize);
    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Putting my QWebEngineView into a dialog still doesn't work:

```
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    auto dialog = new QDialog;
    dialog->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    auto view = new QWebEngineView;
    dialog->layout()->addWidget(view);
    QString html = "<html><body><div width=30px>Text</div></body></html>";
    view->setHtml(html);
    auto contentsSize=view->page()->contentsSize().toSize();
    qDebug() << contentsSize;
    view->setFixedSize(contentsSize);
    dialog->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I also tried to connect to the signal loadFinished, but there is no effect.

```
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    auto dialog = new QDialog;
    dialog->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    auto view = new QWebEngineView;
    dialog->layout()->addWidget(view);
    QString html = "<html><body><div width=30px>Text</div></body></html>";
    view->setHtml(html);
    QObject::connect(view->page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, [&view](bool b) {
        qDebug() << b;
        auto contentsSize = view->page()->contentsSize().toSize();
        qDebug() << contentsSize;
        view->setFixedSize(contentsSize);
    });
    dialog->show();
    return app.exec();
```

}

Comment: Did you try to put your widget on mainwindow or any other layout?

Comment: Yes. I did. I put it into a QDialog. I'll try it again.

Comment: What about using the resize function,  `view->resize(100,100);`

Comment: I don't know beforehand what kind of content I need to display. In Qt 5.3 the equivalent contentsSize function did just the right thing, but now with Qt 5.10 it is somewhat broken, or I need to use it correctly.

Comment: Try to use the signal `QWebEnginePage::contentsSizeChanged`

Comment: This signal is of no help. What I wanted is a function telling me simply the best size for a given HTML content. This was possible with Qt 5.3, this I know for sure.

Comment: view->resize(parent->size()) works fine